# custom validation message works for some errors

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-validator

I have this web application where I have setup bean validation and it works fantastically well. But for one field, it doesn't read the message that I have setup in my validation.properties file. For other fields, it works. I am perplexed as to why this happens? Let me show you my setup:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setCacheSeconds(0);
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    messageSource.setBasenames("/WEB-INF/Validation/validation"); //I have tried setBaseName as well but same difference.
    return messageSource;
}

@Bean
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean() {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    validator.setValidationMessageSource(this.messageSource());
    return validator;
}

@Bean
public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
    MethodValidationPostProcessor processor = new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
    processor.setValidator(this.localValidatorFactoryBean());
    return processor;
}

@Autowired
SpringValidatorAdapter validator; //global validator

@Override
public Validator getValidator() {
    return this.validator;
}
```

My properties file is in correct location. I know that because for some errors, messages are read from this validation.properties file. Location is:

> src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\Validation\validation.properties

Content inside it is:

> validate.user.yearsexperience = Only numbers can be used here.
>
> validate.user.phone = Phone numbers can only be digits and should exactly be 10 digits.
>
> validate.user.name.blank = Name cannot be left empty or Cannot contain more than 30 chars. It will accept letters only. No numbers or symbols are allowed either.

Then I setup following error codes in anticipation of bean validator catching one of these messages (but it did not).

> typeMismatch.user.yearsexperience = Only numbers can be used here.
>
> typeMismatch.yearsexperience  = Only numbers can be used here.
>
> typeMismatch.java.lang.Integer = Only numbers can be used here.
>
> typeMismatch = Only numbers can be used here.

So when I enter wrong data for `phone` or `name` field, JSP shows those messages that I have set in my `validation.properties` file, but for `yearsexperience` field, it shows its own `typeMismatch` or `cannot convert String to Integer, etc exceptions`.

Here let me show you what Annotations I used over my model:

```
public class User{
    @NotBlankNoFancyLettersOrNumbers(message = "{validate.user.name.blank}") //My own custom annotation. Works like a charm and when user enters wrong data, it shows my custom error. 
    private String name;
    @Pattern(regexp="(^$|[0-9]{10})", message = "{validate.user.phone}") //javax's builtin validation constraint
    private String phone;
    @So many things I have tried. But first I started with @Pattern
    private Integer yearsexperience;
```

For this `Integer` field, I cannot use `@Pattern` because it can only be put over `String` fields (am I correct here?).

Then I tried `@Digits`. When a user enters wrong input, it sure works, but doesn't show my error message, it shows a `typeMismatch` exception to the user. Then I made my own custom annotation and I gave it a name `@DigitsOnly`. Same issue, it would't show my error message. It shows the same old `typeMismatch` exception.

At this point, I thought maybe there is a problem with form binding (I should **not** have thought that because bean validation works properly for other fields). Anyway, I registered my own custom editor like this:

```
@InitBinder("user")
protected void binder(WebDataBinder binder, HttpSession session) throws Exception {     
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new DateConvertor()); //This is unrelated to my question but it works!      
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Integer.class, "yearsexperience", new IntegerConvertor(session.getAttribute("user"), this.userdao));
}
```

This is my class that extends `PropertyEditorSupport`:

```
public class IntegerConvertor extends PropertyEditorSupport {   
private User user;  
private UserDAO userdao;
public IntegerConvertor(){}

public IntegerConvertor(Object object, UserDAO userdao) {
    if (object instanceof User){            
        this.user= new User((User) object);
    }
    this.userdao = userdao;
}       

@Override
public void setAsText(String value) {       
if (!value.matches("[0-9]+")) { //if incoming value DOES NOT contains numbers only      
setValue(this.userdao.getYearsExperienceBeforeChange(this.user.getId()));
} else {            
setValue(value);
}       
}
```

Now, I did this in a hope that `typeMismatch` exception will **not** be shown to the user, but still it shows that exception. (I knew that from this `PropertyEditorSupport`, or  it wouldn't read custom error message from `validation.properties` file).

Anyway, then I tried to add a custom validator thru `WebDataBinder.addValidator(myCustomValidator)` like this:

```
 @InitBinder("user")
protected void binder(WebDataBinder binder, HttpSession session) throws Exception {     
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new DateConvertor());       
    binder.addValidators(new myCustormValidator());
}
```

This is how my custom validator looks,

```
public class MyCustormValidator implements Validator {  

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
    return User.class.equals(clazz); //return User.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
}
@Override
public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
    
    User user = (User) target;  
    String a = Integer.toString(user.getYearsExperience());     
    if(!a.matches("[0-9]+")){
        errors.rejectValue("yearsexperience","validate.user.yearsexperience");
    } 
  }
}
```

I converted that `Integer` to `String` because then I was able to check if the incoming value contains digits only and not alphabets. But here it causes another issue: it doesn't show the incoming value, it shows the old value. And because old value was already correct, it doesn't raise any issue. So I added else statement, just to throw an error in a hope that now at least it will show my custom error. But it does not!

Therefore, I have come here for help. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**TL;DR** Why custom error message doesn't show up for one field. But for other fields it works perfectly fine.

Comment: I'd suggest you to enable DEBUG or even TRACE level and see what happens in the logs.

Comment: yes thank you for the suggestion. I will do that at tonight then I will let you know if I find anything.

Comment: I tried. I set log4j2 level to trace and then all. It just wouldn't show me anywhere where the value I entered got rejected. Nowhere! Unless I print the errors manually, there is no mention of my input '55b'. Nowhere is it mentioned where it got rejected. When I try to print the value in myCustomValidator, it just shows the previous value instead of the new one.

Comment: Do you think my global validator could be causing issues? Before it hits myCustomValidator, it hits the global validator and it rejects the value there. Anyway, I just do not see where a value 55b entered by me manually got rejected!

Comment: I gave it another shot. Removed global validator. Set my own validator thru `WebDataBinder.setValidator(..)` (tried `.addValidators(...)` as well), still same issue. Incorrect value doesn't propagate to `myCustomValidator` or to my custom annotation `@DigitsOnly`. Something intercepts it and changes the value to previous value.

Comment: Check for `yearsexperience` in `MyCustormValidator` never will work. Because `User.yearsexperience` field has type `Integer`, Spring MVC will always try to convert user provided value from String to Integer first. This conversion will succeed or if it won't then `typeMismatch` error will be shown. Converting `Integer` to `String` doesn't make sense because it will always pass the check in this case.

Comment: If you're able to prepare http://sscce.org I can take a look.

Comment: Hello Slava I have prepared a sscce project for you to test. I shall be thankful to you. This project is here: https://github.com/farazdurrani/sscce

Comment: @SlavaSemushin for now, I am just adding input type="number" in my JSP. That way a user cannot enter non-numbers. And I am happy with that. Btw, I added a github link where I created a sscce. Did you get a chance to look at it?

Comment: I've updated my answer. I believe that this will solve your issue with localization. For other difficulties, please, create separate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why the custom error doesn't show up for some fields but for others it works perfectly fine

Because there are two different components are involved:

- hibernate-validator that is using for bean validation
- spring-mvc that is binding user values from a to a POJO class

You've properly configured message source for bean validation and it works.

But then you're customizing `typeMismatch` message and looks like Spring MVC doesn't see this. Typically it's enough to define bean with name `messageSource` but for some strange reason in your case you need something else.

My guess is that you have 2 contexts and `messageSource` is defined in the context that isn't visible to Spring MVC.

---

**UPDATE:**
I looked into example project on GitHub (http://github.com/farazdurrani/sscce) and I see that the problem with non-working `typeMismatch` message not because of the configuration. It happens because you're not using standard tags and try to show error messages manually (by invoking `getDefaultMessage()` method on each error from `Errors.getAllErrors()`). If you try to use `<form:errors path="*"/>`, you'll see that all error messages have been properly localized.

Comment: Salava thanks for taking a look at my question and responding. I have only one application context. It is the root context. I know that because my bootstrap class is extending AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer. And in that I am overriding, getRootConfigClasses() and I return only one class like this: new Class<?>[] { RootContextConfiguration.class };.

Comment: Did you try to specify `basename` as `WEB-INF/Validation/validation` (without leading slash)?

Comment: about hibernate validator: I am only using java API (like java.beans.PropertyEditorSupport, javax.validation.ConstraintValidator, or spring's api like: org.springframework.validation.Validator, etc.

Comment: first I am sorry for getting your name wrong in my first comment. Slava, I have not tried it, but I will try it later because as of now, I have changed my code considerably.

Comment: Most likely you're using `hibernate-validator` as an implementation. It's possible to use another provider (AFAIR Apache BVAL` but it's used very rare).

Comment: It is indeed hibernate-validator. The LocalValidatorFactoryBean that I return in my config file looks for bean validation implementation hibernate validator in the classpath. And I do have hibernate-validator in my classpath

Comment: I tried WEB-INF/Validation/validation (without leading slash) but same issue.

Comment: If your project is open source then you can provide a link and I'll try to debug it, otherwise someone else will help you (or you have to debug it yourself).

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not. But thanks for your kind offer.

Comment: Hi. I have provided some more information under the **EDIT**. Maybe that can provide some hint to a solution

Comment: Thank you very much that is exactly the solution. Adding errors to model was not the right solution. I did exactly what you said above and that solved it! Thanks!!!!